# Store File in Java

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a web UI and a spring based rest service.The UI has two buttons upload and download.When Upload is called a call goes to my REST service .The rest service will get the file and store it in machine .

Browser(Upload File)---->Service(Get File and store the file)

How can I store the received file on my appliance.My skeleton of the rest service is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void putFile(@RequestParam(value="fileName", required=false) File fileName,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

    What do I do here ,How can I store the received file .
    }
```

Also from as a part of the request ,can my javascript send the file to the  server ?

Comment: You can write a Spring based REST client but do not know how to write data into a file? Or do you think this is a code writing service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MultipartFile to get the actual file in Spring.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/upload")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                               @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    ...
}
```

[Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) is the proper example.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is available in the request body, maybe something like this:

```
InputStream requestInputStream = request.getInputStream();
OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

final int bufferSize = 4096;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

int byteCount;
while( (byteCount=requestInputStream.read(buffer)) != 0 ) {
    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, /*offset = 0*/ 0, byteCount);
}

fileOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: How do i store it in a place say /home/user/FileStorage

Comment: OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/user/FileStorage/<filename>"));

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void putFile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) throws Exception {
    InputStream templateInputStream = null;
    if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
        for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : fileUpload) {
            templateInputStream = aFile.getInputStream();
            convertStreamToFile(templateInputStream, new File("/home/user/FileStorage/<filename>"));
            templateInputStream.reset();
            break;
        }
    }
}

    public void convertStreamToFile(InputStream is, File file) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        BufferedWriter fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileWriter.write(line + "\n");
        }
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();
        is.close();

    }
```